# How do I remove headers from a $http.get request and also add "application/json" and "text/plain" to "Accept"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I am a newbie to angularjs and I am trying to add some new functionality to an existing angular js app.
All the existing calls are wrapped in complex logic so I thought I would make a call directly. Here is the code for my call:

[image: code for my new call]

When existing calls are made to the api from the angularjs code they work and have the following headers in the top of the image below (marked with "Works" in red text). My new call adds Access-Control-Request-Headers and Access-Control-Request-Method like in the bottom half of the image below (marked with "Fails" in red text).

[image: success and failing calls]

When I look in the Console of Chrome I see the following error for my new request: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/blablabla/v1/login.json. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

I am also missing "application/json" and "text/plain" from the "Accept" header in the request. How can I add these to "Accept" and also get rid of the "Access-Control-Request-Headers" and "Access-Control-Request-Method"?

Comment: Can't you do a bit digging to the 'complex logic' you mentioned to check how it's done there? Even if you make it work imho you should follow existing standards in the app you try to extend.

Answer (score 0):

Please find an example of setting $http request options below:

```
 var request = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'http://example.com',
   headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json'
   },
   data: { test: 'test' }
 }

 $http(request ).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am also missing "application/json" and "text/plain" from the "Accept" header in the request. How can I add these to "Accept"

The browser is making a [preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). You should expect to see the header you desire when it subsequently makes a GET request having received permission from the server to make it.

(Your real problem is, most likely, that you haven't set up the server to properly respond to the preflight request.)

> and also get rid of the "Access-Control-Request-Headers" and "Access-Control-Request-Method"?

Short of removing the conditions which require a prelight request in the first place: You can't. These are added automatically by the browser when it makes the preflight request.

Comment: Other calls from the same application manage to call the webapi fine. So the server will not be an issue. The only difference between my newly added call and the working calls is the things I pointed out. I need to modify my call to be like the other calls.

Comment: @DotNetGuy — So the difference is that you are customising the request headers … which is something that can trigger a preflight request. Are the other calls triggering preflight requests?

Comment: I also tried sending the get request without specifying the headers (ie. without passing in the config var). So the $http.get request only had 2 parameters specified, the url and the parameters json object. this resulted in the same error. The other get calls from the angularjs app also use $http.get but do not pass "Access-Control-Request-Headers" and "Access-Control-Request-Method", but do pass "application/json" and "text/plain" in the "Accept" header (which my call does not).

Comment: @DotNetGuy — It also passes `*/*`, so what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the call does not get to the API and I get this message "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/blablabla/v1/shops/select.json. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers." in the console of Chrome.

Comment: @DotNetGuy — That has nothing to do with the Accept header though. You need to configure the server so it uses CORS to tell the browser that cross origin requests with an Authorization header are OK.